# mysql insert statment using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to insert the following data to supplier table:

```
   supplier_account_id,
   supplier_name,
   supplier_address,
   supplier_contact_number
```

Once the process is done, the data are accepted except for supplier contact number which contains nothing but zero(0), but it does not prompt any error message.

Kindly help me solve this. Please refer to the statement below. Thank you.

```
$insert_into_supplier = $new_batch_marketing->query("INSERT INTO supplier (`supplier_account_id`, `supplier_name`, `supplier_address`, `supplier_contact_number`) VALUES ('".$supplier_id."','$supplier_name', '$supplier_address', '$supplier_contact_number')");
```

Comment: could you try this                                                                       $insert_into_supplier = $new_batch_marketing->query("INSERT INTO supplier (supplier_account_id, supplier_name, supplier_address, supplier_contact_number) VALUES ('".$supplier_id."','".$supplier_name."', '".$supplier_address."', '".$supplier_contact_number."')");

Comment: is your column name supplier_contact_number is in type integer ? can you give an example of value you are trying to save to database in column supplier_contact_number ?

Comment: It works! Thank you@weekDaw